# Why is the president so restless?

Tags: plot-explanation, being-there

After Chance appears on a tv show, the president is so restless that he has no desire for sex. This happens at least once more in the movie, and I wonder what the issue is. Maybe he's already concerned the now-popular Chance would defeat him in a possible future contest (for U.S. presidency)? If so, are we given enough detail in the movie to justify him acting this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two explanations I have for the President's apparent impotence are:

1. His mind is on other things, such as the now-popular Chance - and this distraction is making it difficult for him to focus on his sexual life.
2. His sexual impotence is symbolic and reflective of his impotence as the leader of the country.